# How do i loop through each line of a file after it has been used as an argument?

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have this script called `install-plugins.sh` that installs plugins into jenkins.

```
#!/bin/bash

JENKINS_URL=http://localhost:8080
PLUGINS_FILE=$1

while IFS=':' read -r plugin_name plugin_version; do
  java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s $JENKINS_URL -auth admin:admin install-plugin "${plugin_name}:${plugin_version}"
done < "$PLUGINS_FILE"

java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s $JENKINS_URL -auth admin:admin safe-restart
```

I also have a txt file that has the plugin names and their versions

```
run-condition:1.5
blueocean-dashboard:1.27.1
blueocean-core-js:1.27.1
```

Whenever I run the script, the **first plugin is only installed** but not the others below. How do I fix this?

```
./install-plugins.sh plugins.txt

Installing run-condition:1.5 from update center
```

Comment: I'm guessing your `java` command consumes the rest of standard input. Try `java -blah -blah </dev/null`

Comment: See [BashFAQ/089](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `java` will consume the rest of the STDIN. So,

```
run-condition:1.5
```

is read by the `while read`, and

```
blueocean-dashboard:1.27.1
blueocean-core-js:1.27.1
```

is read by `java`.

A simple solution would be to give `java` its own STDIN to chew on:

```
while IFS=':' read -r plugin_name plugin_version; do
  echo 'hoppa' | java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s $JENKINS_URL -auth admin:admin install-plugin "${plugin_name}:${plugin_version}"
done < "$PLUGINS_FILE"
```